# Can you have more than one indicator in an XSD complex element?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, validationrules

I'm trying to build a new schema to validate XML against for my job. But I'm having a hard time answering the question: can I and how do I create a complex element that has some elements that need to be in a set sequence and other subelements that do not? Ultimately I think I should be able to have opening and closing "sequence" tags and opening and closing "all" tags around two sets of elements, but xsd doesn't seem to like that. Here's what I have:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Original">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="AssetIdentifier" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Definition: The Asset Identifier element is intended to
                        reflect the root of all following digital filenames.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ArchiveID" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Definition: The Filename element in this section is
                        intended to reflect the root of all the following derivative digital
                        filenames.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Title" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Definition: The known title of the asset. If no title is
                        known, one can be assigned; a number or letter sequence, whichever is
                        the most logical. Using the value "unknown" is also
                        acceptable.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="RecordDate" type="xsd:date">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Definition: The actual recording date of the asset.
                        Estimates, partial dates, and date ranges (i.e. 19XX, Feb. 19-24,
                        1934-1935, etc.) are allowable, as is 'unknown'. Best practice, when
                        applicable, is to use the YYYY-MM-DD format in accordance with ISO 8601.
                        Even partial dates, i.e. 1990-05 should adhere to this
                        format.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="FormatType" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Definition: The format of the analog asset, i.e. Open
                        Reel, Grooved Disc, DAT, Cassette, VHS, 16mm film, EIAJ,
                        etc.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Best Practice: The MediaPreserve maintains a list of
                        controlled vocabularies organized by media type at: www.dontknowyet.com.
                        However, MP opted to meake this an unrestricted element in the event
                        that other ogranizations have their own controlled vocabularies in
                        place.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="StockBrand" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>If known definitively</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeModel" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>If applicable. Usually applies to DAT tapes, open reels,
                        and wire recordings.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeWidth" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Typically only applicable for open reel
                        audio</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
```

Comment: I think I understand, but please can you confirm _exactly_ which ordering of child tags are allowed and which are not allowed. Obviously '123ABCD' and '123DCAB' are allowed and  '321ABCD' is not allowed. But what about '1A2B3CD'? The 1,2,3 are in the correct order, but are not consecutive.

Comment: also...please can you be more specific about this comment: "xsd doesn't seem to like that.". If possible, post the exact text of the error message.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking me to confirm? I have a root element of a complex type. I want that element to contain a bunch of other elements, some need to be in a particular sequence, others do not. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSDs unfortunately do not allow what you're trying to do (combine `<sequence/>` and `<all />` inside a single complex type or element). You might be able to achieve something similar with a nested content model, but note you can't nest `<all>` except under another `<all />`, otherwise you must define it in another element. You can however, nest either `<sequence>` or `<choice>` under each other.

From my understanding of XSDs, you have 3 viable options.

The first is to nest all the elements you want under `<all />` to be contained within their own sub-element:

```
<xs:complexType name="Original">
  <xs:sequence>
    <!-- AssetIdentifier to FormatType left out for brevity -->
    <xs:element name="Misc">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="StockBrand" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeModel" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeWidth" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- For the above, valid XML would be: -->
<Original>
  <AssetIdentifier>AssetIdentifier0</AssetIdentifier>
  <Title>Title0</Title>
  <RecordDate>2006-05-04</RecordDate>
  <FormatType>FormatType0</FormatType>
  <Misc>
    <!-- Optional & order doesn't matter -->
    <StockBrand>what</StockBrand>
    <TapeWidth>1290</TapeWidth>
    <TapeModel>Hey</TapeModel>
  </Misc>
</Original>
```

Second is to nest those elements under another `<sequence />`, which allows you to forgo specifying another sub-element, but now requires the elements appear in order as specified in the schema. Note that the nested sequence itself can be optional.

```
<xs:complexType name="Original">
  <xs:sequence>
    <!-- AssetIdentifier to FormatType left out for brevity -->
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="StockBrand" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeModel" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TapeWidth" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- For the above, valid XML would be: -->
<Original>
  <AssetIdentifier>AssetIdentifier0</AssetIdentifier>
  <Title>Title0</Title>
  <RecordDate>2006-05-04</RecordDate>
  <FormatType>FormatType0</FormatType>
  <!-- Optional below, but must be ordered -->
  <StockBrand>what</StockBrand>
  <TapeModel>Hey</TapeModel>
  <TapeWidth>1290</TapeWidth>
</Original>
```

There's a third option that is a bit of a 'hack', but still allows specifying elements go unordered, still remain optional, yet still appear adjacent to the other mandatory, in-order elements. This nests a choice (with **maxOccurs="3"**) under sequence, inside the parent sequence (sequence > sequence > choice):

```
<xs:complexType name="Original">
  <xs:sequence>
    <!-- AssetIdentifier to FormatType left out for brevity -->
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="StockBrand" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="TapeModel" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="TapeWidth" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- For the above, valid XML would be: -->
<Original>
  <AssetIdentifier>AssetIdentifier0</AssetIdentifier>
  <Title>Title0</Title>
  <RecordDate>2006-05-04</RecordDate>
  <FormatType>FormatType0</FormatType>
  <!-- Optional, unordered, but there's a catch: -->
  <TapeWidth>1290</TapeWidth>
  <StockBrand>what</StockBrand>
  <TapeModel>Hey</TapeModel>
</Original>
```

There's a catch with this 3rd option however, the `maxOccurs="3"` on the `<choice />` element renders the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` on the child elements (`StockBrand`, `TapeModel` and `TapeWidth`) meaningless; which means those elements, while still remaining optional, can now appear more than once, so long as the cumulative total of elements is still 3 or less:

This becomes valid (2 of the same element + 1 more):

```
  <TapeWidth>1290</TapeWidth>
  <TapeWidth>1291</TapeWidth>
  <TapeModel>Hey</TapeModel>
```

And this is still valid (3 of the same):

```
  <TapeWidth>1290</TapeWidth>
  <TapeWidth>1291</TapeWidth>
  <TapeWidth>1292</TapeWidth>
```

And also this (just 1 occurence of 1 element):

```
  <StockBrand>1290</StockBrand>
```

You could probably try to find another option by fiddling with the combination of sequence and choice nesting, but it's best practice to keep your schemas simple. Personally I would recommend the first 2 options over the third purely to keep your schema simple.

Comment: Thank you very much!!